# Linear Approximation for functions with first derivative as $0$

Tags: approximation, linear-approximation

Linear approximation around a point through Taylor series requires the first order derivative to be non-zero unless you want to get only the value at that point. However this is only true when you are extremely close to the referred point. Is there a better way to linearly approximate such a function.

For example, using Taylor Series to evaluate linear approximation of the function, $f(x) = (1+x^2)^{1/2}$, yields $1$ which is really true if you are extremely close to $x=0$. Also it is not a first order approximation since its constant.

Is there another way to approximate, lets say, if I know the lower and upper bounds on $x$?

Comment: If you use 0 for the 1st order term you have a bound on the error (Lagrange's remainder). If you use something else for the 1st order term you don't know, in general. BTW, a constant _is_ a particular case of a linear approximation

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the first-order approximation being constant. It just means the function is rather flat near that point. After all, how else would you approximate a function that actually *is* constant? Or what about the function $x\mapsto x^{100}+ 7$ near $x=0$?

Comment: @LuisMendo sorry I didn't get the first part...the only better way I can think of is to use the middle point of my bounds and approximate there...As for the constant being a particular case of linear approximation I am not sure since using this argument a lower order polynomial is always a particular case of a higher order polynomial

Comment: @MPW I can understand what you mean but I was wondering if there is another way to approximate if your margin of error is relatively large

Comment: If you require *linear* approximation, then move the center to another point which is closer to the point at which you need to evaluate the approximation. Approximations are implicitly *local* approximations, which means they are only valid for small neighborhoods, not globally.

Comment: @MPW yeah thats what I meant by umaking use of the bounds...i was wondering if there is another way that is more robust for these type of functions...but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I will use your function as an example. The pointwise error of linear approximation can be defined as 
$$dE=\big(\sqrt{1+x^2}-ax-b \big)^2$$
If you integrate the error over your domain (let's say from $-x_1$ to $x_1$) you find the total error over the domain
$$E=\int_{-x_1}^{x_1}dE=\int_{-x_1}^{x_1}\big(\sqrt{1+x^2}-ax-b \big)^2dx$$
Completing the integration you get the closed form for total error
$$E= \frac23(1+a^2)x_1^3+2x_1\bigg(1+b^2-b\sqrt{1+x_1^2}\bigg)-2b\text{ArcSinh(}x_1\text{)}$$
Now you can minimize the error by taking the partial derivatives wrt a and b; equating the equations to zero.

Comment: appreciate the comment but it is a least square fit... and since the function as well as the bounds are symmetric, it would give you a constant...I was wondering more in the sense of different kinds of approximation algorithms like the Taylor series approximation... :)

Comment: @Zero Taylor series approximation is a local one. It only approximates the function close to your evaluation point irrespective of the bounds. You can vary the algorithm by increasing the norm and/or adding constraints for slope.